# How to restrict operations to certain lines?

Tags: vim

I have to work on some relatively huge code files in vim.

How do I restrict some operations like find-next `normal-n` and others to a certain function / block?

How would I visually know if I'm within that block or outside it?

Looking and line numbers seems awkward, specially that the line numbers I need to work with are generally 5 digits long!

Comment: @Closers: Since this deals with using vim to manipulate source code, SO can be more appropriate than SU. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43198/emacs-questions-superuser-or-stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set marks at the beginning and end of your block using `m` (e.g. `ma`, `mb`) and then refer to them in the range of a ex command as `:'a,'b`.

Like [bignose said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543437/how-to-restrict-operations-to-certain-lines/2543472#2543472) you can use a visual block to create an implicit region for a command, which can be passed to an ex command using `:'<,'>`

You can also use regexes to delimit a block (e.g. for all the lines between `start` and `end` use `:/start/,/end/`

For example, to make a substitution in a range of lines:

```
:'<,'>s/foo/bar/g
:'a,'bs/baz/quux/g
:/harpo/,/chico/s/zeppo/groucho/g
```

The last visually selected range is remembered so you can reuse it without reselecting it.

For more on ranges, see `:help range`

You can further restrict yourself within a range by using `g//`.  For example, if you wanted to replace foo with bar only on lines containing baz in the selected range:

```
:'<,'>g/baz/s/foo/bar/g
```

When you define a new ex command, you can pass the range given to the ex-command using as `<line1>,<line2>`.  See `:help user-commands` for more on defining ex-commands.

Within a vimscript function, you can access an implicitly passed range using `a:firstline` and `a:lastline`.  You can detect your current linenumber using `line('.')`, and detect whether you're inside the block using normal boolean logic (`a:firstline <= line('.') && line('.') <= a:lastline`). See `:help functions` for more on vimscript functions.

---

Another approach, is to use vim's inner `i` and single `a` selectors.  For example, to delete the entirety of a double quoted string, use `da"` in normal mode.  To leave the quotes, use `di"`.  See `:help object-select` for more.

Answer (score 1):

[Vimtips](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Vim_Tips_Wiki) has exactly what you were looking for:

[Search in current function](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_in_current_function)

See also [`:help pattern-atoms`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#pattern-atoms)

Answer (score 0):

Vim uses `Shift-v` to select by lines. Having selected a series of lines, many commands will then be restricted to the selection.

I don't think the search commands (`/`, `n`, etc.) are restricted that way though.

Comment: Don't add [belongs-on-XXX] tags. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10216/can-we-disallow-the-use-of-belongs-on-xxxxxxx-and-not-programming-related-tag

Comment: But then I have to be in visual select mode all the time.  Not convenient.

Answer (score 0):

For commands like search and replace, you can easily limit yourself to a couple of lines:

```
:.,+3s/foo/bar/cg
```

replaces every occurrence of "foo" in the current line and the following 3 lines with "bar". I don't think you can do that for search, though.

Comment: problem is, my "block" to manipulate is over 1000 lines, from a total of over 20k.  And I may add / delete lines, so that would not work.

Comment: well, if you do dozens or more operations on it, it's not too much trouble to open a new window, cut&paste the selected lines and when you're done, paste the updated text back.